# How to connect to a database with Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle, connection

I need to connect to a database with `Oracle SQL-Developer`.

What I know from the DB is the Instance name and a Database Role.

How do I connect to the database or what more information do I need?

Comment: Do you have username and password?

Answer (score 4):

Oracle has excellent documentation on creating connections in SQL Developer both within the application help, but also on their technology network website: [OTN Getting Started with SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/getting-started-155046.html). This viewlet found on that page nicely walks you through the process [Connect to Database](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/sqldev/dbconnection/database_connection_viewlet_swf.html).

You will need a username and password, the hostname and port, and a SID.

Comment: where does one find those username, pasword, hostname, port and sid?